# Materialized view created successfully but giving query too long error on refreshing

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, materialized-views

I have created a materialized view.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW apps.RPRO_BILLED_CONTRACTS_MV
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH SYSDATE
NEXT (sysdate+1/1440) with rowid
AS "query";
```

it got created successfully and is returning rows on select * operation.
However I wanted to check whether it is refreshing or not and turns out it was not.
I ran the manual refresh command as :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('RPRO_BILLED_CONTRACTS_MV');
end;
```

Now this returns error:
Error report

```
ORA-32411: materialized view definition query exceeds the maximum length
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2563
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2776
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2745
ORA-06512: at line 2

32411. 0000 -  "materialized view definition query exceeds the maximum length"
*Cause:    The materialized view definition query exceeds the 64K limit.
*Action:   Change the materialized view definition query so that it does not exceed
           the maximum length of 64K.
```

I'm confused, if the query is too long, how come the view got created and returning values but not refreshing. Please help.

Comment: So **is the total length of your query > 64K**?

Comment: yes its > 64k, but why the view is getting created and fetching rows then.

Comment: According to [this AskTom question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:41742083561301) there is no limit on the length of an SQL statement. [The 64K limit on materialized view queries is documented here for 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm); however, I could not find a corresponding documented limit on materialized view query length in 11.1. As to "why is there such a limit", perhaps you should repost this question on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `CREATE` process for a Materialized View is different to the `REFRESH` process.

During `CREATE`, the Materialized View can be created using any length SQL statement. During `REFRESH`, the 64K limit described below is enforced:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

A possible workaround is to chain your materialized view creation. If you can breakdown your query into smaller chunks you can build your final materialized view using a subquery that itself references materialized views.